# tensorflow expantion a, b = t1[1:3]

Tags: tensorflow

Is this guaranteed to work in the future release as well?

```
import tensorflow as tf

t1 = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
a, b = t1[1:3]
print(f"a:{a} b:{b}")
---
a:1 b:2
```

Not sure if this is Python feature which may not work in the future or a feature supported by Tensorflow as bulit-in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is part of [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor_slicing#extract_tensor_slices).

> Perform NumPy-like tensor slicing using [`tf.slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice).
>
> ```py
> t1 = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>
> print(tf.slice(t1,
>                begin=[1],
>                size=[3]))
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can use a more Pythonic syntax. Note that tensor slices are evenly spaced over a start-stop range.
>
> ```py
> print(t1[1:4])
> ```